# Do I need scanned copy or original invitation letter for Russian (Humanitarian) visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, russia, invitation-letters

I am an Indian student born and raised in India. I am currently a research scholar. I have published some research work in Russia, I will be going to Russia for presenting the research paper. In the visa process, I need an invitation letter, I am not sure whether I need **original or scanned one**. If I ask for the original it may take a few weeks to arrive the original letter. I am applying for Humanitarian type of visa. Please Help.

Note that I will be staying for a week in russia.

**Question** : Do I need scanned copy or original invitation letter for Russian (Humanitarian) visa?

Answer (score 1):

A scanned, color copy is what most people use to apply with. Normally the tourist agency does not mail you the original letter of invitation, they simply email you a scanned color copy, which is acceptable to apply with.

You could request the original to be mailed to you, but I have had a lot of problems with mail delivery to and from Russia, so I wouldn't get your hopes up of it arriving in time or arriving at all.

I have never received an original letter of invitation and I have been to Russia four times on 3 different Russian visas.